# Is it possible to run Docker multi-stage build images on older versions of Docker?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Creating multi stage builds requires Docker 17.05. Once created is it possible to use these images on older versions of the Docker daemon, or are the images themselves in a slightly different format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's possible.  The image format has not changed.  It's just the build process that changed.